# How to write « and » in Galaxy A30s?

Tags: samsung, keyboard

Oftentimes I write texts that require the usage of a combination between ', " and «. Yet I have to copy from anywhere « anytime I want to use it and that's not the nicest experience.

This is the variations the keyboard offers

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, the only keyboard key that looks closer to « is 《 which is not really the same. I did long press some of the existing keyboard keys but none revealed the «.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take was to search for "keyboard"

[image]

Go to "Manage keyboards"

[image]

And activate Gboard.

Now I can simply long press "

[image]

And that opens up a modal with the « and ».